# .htaccess Rewrite url to query string

Tags: .htaccess, query-string

When I upload images to my website, their links look like this:

https://mywebsite.com/photo/9/
etc.. only the number changes

I want to rewrite it to be query string, like this:

https://mywebsite.com/p?id=9
etc..

This is what I tried to do, but it doesn't work:

```
RewriteRule ^/photo/([0-9]+) /p?id=$1
```

Comment: When you say you want it rewritten? What do you want to display in the browser bar? Let's start with that.

Comment: I want to rewrite the web address completely, so it will open by the query string and show it in the browser bar and not the old one

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^photo/([^/]*)$ /p?id=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the leading slash from RewriteRule's pattern,try :

```
RewriteRule ^photo/([0-9]+)/?$ /p?id=$1 [L]
```